# How to change Exposure when it is not possible

Tags: camera

If i understand correctly, exposure is the measure of lightness in a picture. In my phone, there are no settings by which I can set it manually (it does it automatically), I use to put my hand on camera and then remove it suddenly and take a shot to get higher exposure when needed. For low exposure I use to face camera towards a lights source then suddenly back to the point and take a shot.

This is an ugly way to do it, is there any software or technique which can do that??

Comment: Why don't you try other camera apps? There are tons of them in Play store.

Comment: I have tried many and the exposure settings don't change anything

Comment: Then I think you should edit your question to reflect the fact that the exposure settings in most of the camera app doesn't work the intended way.

Comment: @roxan I read somewhere that my phone and many other does not support manual exposure settings, I was wondering if some app can still do that

Answer (score 3):

If you can't adjust the exposure even with third-party camera apps, the only solution would seem to be adjusting it in post-processing. For example [Photoshop Express](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.psmobile) can do this right on the phone. Or you can use your favorite image editor after you move the photos to your PC.

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading [Pudding Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kth.PuddingCamera&hl=en).

There is a little wheel on the left side you can turn to change exposure.